# Some Static Content Loads Very Slowly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm attempting to install an MVC 2 web application to our production server.  This app has been run and tested on several test servers, but in production, some static content (most notably JavaScript files) load very, very slowly (sometimes 60+ seconds).  What's interesting, however, is that this isn't the case for all static content--during a typical page load cycle, all but one of the JS files will be successfully transferred to the client, but one will "stick" and sometimes never download.

What's also odd is that if I go directly to the static content, it loads immediately.

I've investigated the handler mappings, and compared the IIS configuration to our test environment, and everything is similar.  What would cause this?

Comment: Are you keeping all of your static content in a separate folder? You could add a `routes.IgnoreRoute("StaticFolder/{*pathInfo}");` route handler to prevent the MVC engine even trying to resolve those routes to actions.

Comment: Yes, my static content is separate.  Interestingly, it may be a network routing issue: when accessing the site from my home, I didn't experience any of the delays in serving static content.

Comment: I had a similar issue once that was traced to a timing mismatch between some of our network architecture.

Comment: Interestingly, it is partially downloading the content of the JS files.  It is just really, really slow.

Comment: Laurence, how did you discover the timing mismatch?

Comment: It was my manager at the time, he was running a packet tracer and saw that we were dropping packets like crazy. Fix the mismatch, our packet success rate goes up, we get a 3 second increase in page load time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in webconfig file for static contents , it will compress the file & result in fast rendering of page

```
 <system.webServer>

<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true"/>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```